# CameraMovement during frequent location updates

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I am looking for best practice advice regarding the cameraMovement in a mapView.
I am retrieving location updates every few seconds right now and I wonder how you best handle the cameraMovement.
I want to enable the user to scroll around the map and explore some of the places + read the text in the infoWindows without the camera constantly recentering around the current user location.
Can you recommend me, how to handle this the best way possible?

```
public LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(100000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(20000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    return locationRequest;
}
```

This is called in the location callback.

```
public void createLocationCallback() {
mLocationCallback =new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult (LocationResult locationResult){
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Location: " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getTime());
            mLastKnownLocation = location;
            updateLocationUI(location);
            updateLocationOnFirebase();
            displayLocationData();
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see, for each newly retrieved location, the updateLocationUI method is called, recentering the camera around the current location.

```
private void updateLocationUI(Location mLastKnownLocation) {
    if (mGoogleMap == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                            mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
            Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                    "Retrieving location update", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Current location null. Use defaults here");
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a timer which is started/restarted when user touches/moves map and sets a flag.  If flag is set then don't move camera.  If timer expires clear flag.  Set timer duration to whatever you think is how long user will not want the recenter feature.  Alternative, have user clear flag with button; so whenever user starts moving around it will only recenter to location after user reenables with button - such as the mylocation button.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try around in this direction. I tried to iterate through the locations and only moveCamera in the first location object, but didnt work the way I thought it could. Would you recommend to just stop calling the function that updates the UI, while the map is touched? Also from a performance perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually solved it another way now. Simply designed two different methods (one recentering camera around the location, one without recentering) and declared a boolean firstRun that is true every time the fragment is created.

If true, the initial method that recenters the camera around the location, is called and the boolean value gets set to false.

Whenever the value is false, the regular method is called that handles the location updates, but doesnt recenter the camera.

For recentering, the location button provided by Google can be used.

I was thinking way too complicated and this is a simple solution doing exactly what I need :)